# Retire a domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, migration, domain-controller

I need to retire a particular piece of hardware, I have another server online on this particular network.

I have run DCPromo om the new server, but when the original server is shutdown, authentication on the network fails. I have also made the new 2003 server a global catalogue, and authentication still fails.

I would like to know how I can 'retire' the old server. It may need to stay on the network for legacy reasons, but I would dearly love to remove all domain activity from it without any downtime.

I look forward to help in this regards! Thanks for your tips hints and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

transfer the [FSMO roles](http://www.petri.co.il/transferring_fsmo_roles.htm) to the new server, then demote the old server using dcpromo again

you may also want to check the replication status of your new server using `repadmin /showrepl`

Comment: I am currently moving RID, PCD, and Infastructure roles to a secondary 2003 server, with buckets, and buckets of bandwith. I am assuming that, this *should* improve the domain performance?

Comment: Improve the domain performance in what way? What performance problems are you having that you attribute to the domain controller?

Comment: The Domain Controller also has other applications that have been put on it such as exchange tomcat, and mysql (management decisions). I want to move all domain related roles away from this server, to another server that does *nothing* except these five roles. Am I missing the mark here?

Comment: No, I think that's a wise choice. Use the DC for DC related functions and use application servers for applications.

Comment: which version of exchange? you wont want to demote a DC with exchange 2007+ on it, instead install exchange on a new server and migrate

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add the new DC to the client ip settings for DNS, assuming your DC is also your DNS server.

Comment: I added this system to the DHCP settings - Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you Promote your new Servers as a DNS Server and all the objects replicate between both the Domain Controller.

Before you demote the existing Domain Controller please ensure that you [Transfer FSMO Roles](http://www.itingredients.com/what-is-fsmo-roles-flexible-single-master-operations/) else you'll face many other issues in your environment than you are facing now.

Comment: Read the other answers first. Your contribution to this question: 0.